# Linux USB mass storage gadget issues with large drives

Tags: linux, usb-storage, linux-kernel

I'm trying to make a linux device act as a large USB drive with a USB port in OTG/device mode. The g_mass_storage module works well with backing files up to 2Tb of size, but I can't find a way to expose an 8Tb drive using this module. It seems like the module is limited to 512 bytes blocks then using backing files. The documentation states that, when using a block device, the module will use the block size of the device. I tried using a partitioned and formated 8Tb file via a loop device in stead of using the file directly to see if that would convince g_mass_storage to use larger blocks, but that didn't help. Are there any alternative modules or another way to accomplish this?

Comment: First thing I'd do is to read the source code of g_mass_storage, and check where the physical/logical block sizes are coming from.

Comment: I did read it, and the files where things actually happens as well, but I'm not a developer so i find it hard to understand. The block size seems to come from constants defined elsewhere.